# Unexpected side-effect of ternary conditional operator in Java 1.4

Tags: java, long-integer, ternary-operator, java1.4

I ran into an unexpected bug today involving a ternary conditional operator in Java 1.4.

The following code did not produce the intended results:

```
product.setValue((finalAmount == 0) ? StringUtils.EMPTY : ConversionUtil.bigDecimalToString(value) + " " + code);
product.setNumber((finalAmount == 0) ? StringUtils.EMPTY : ConversionUtil.formatLongToAmountString(new Long(finalAmount)));
```

When `finalAmount == 0`, `Value` is set to BlahBlahStuff, not `""`. Number, however, is correctly set.

However, this worked:

```
if (finalAmount == 0) {
    product.setValue(StringUtils.EMPTY);
    product.setNumber(StringUtils.EMPTY);
}
else {
    product.setValue(ConversionUtil.bigDecimalToString(value) + " " + code);
    product.setNumber(ConversionUtil.formatLongToAmountString(new Long(finalAmount)));
}
```

Why would the test work on a line but not the other?
`finalAmount` is a primitive `long`, and is local to this method.

**Disclaimers** - I know that:

1. Using Java 1.4 in 2013 is a heresy. I do not call the shots about that, sadly.
2. The working solution, despite being less compact, is actually more efficient, as the test is not repeated twice. I'm just interested in understanding why the first one did not work.

Comment: Is `finalAmount` accessed by various threads in your program?

Comment: No, it's a local variable... good idea thus, I forgot to mention that. I'll edit the question to reflect this.

Comment: Is this miserable behavior exhibiting everytime you run the code?

Comment: Yes, although changing the value of the various variables can be tricky in this app, so I couldn't test with many different values.

Comment: Have you tested it on java version > 1.4 ? And even if the problem persist then I would like to go through the method wrapping up these codes. And also the part of the program where this method is called..

Comment: Thank you for your perseverance (+1). However I can't afford to spend too much time on this problem : I was expecting a simple mistake on my part about the way ternary operators work. I will add a comment in the code about this, and move on for now. Some refactoring must be done around this code, so I'll update this question or add my own answer if I find the solution then. :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is order of operations.  The ternary operator is evaluated first, then the concatenation is applied to the result of the ternary operator expression.  Try this instead (put parentheses around the string concatenation expressions):

```
product.setValue((finalAmount == 0) ? StringUtils.EMPTY : (ConversionUtil.bigDecimalToString(value) + " " + code));
```

Comment: This is ... incorrect. The operands to a ternary operation, as delineated by the `:` are separate expressions. The ternary operation is compiled into a branch in byte code and depending on which branch 'fires' either the LHS or RHS expressions will be executed.

Comment: Hmm.  Okay - I didn't actually check the precedence, I just use parentheses in my code so it is clear and order is never a problem.  I just tried the code using OpenJDK 1.6 (I no longer have a 1.4 environment installed) and it worked.  I'll delete this answer later if a better/correct answer is provided.

Comment: no, your code works just fine, explicitly grouping operations with brackets is often a good idea. ***But***, its not the reason the OP's code is failing. Ternary operator behavior has not changed between releases of the JDK afaik, and his code works (as expected) in JDK 6.

Answer (score 1):

If the `finalAmount` is shared among various threads then It should be declared as `volatile`. So that each Thread always read the latest value of `finalAmount` , because each thread caches the `finalAmount` value locally that leads to `stale data` read by Threads. Declaring the variable as `volatile` ensures that the data read by each thread would be the latest one.

Comment: Good idea, but no. `finalAlount` is a local variable.